# How to Right-to-Left a Spotify Follow Button?

Tags: spotify

Can I structure a Spotify follow button so that it is displayed [right-to-left](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/09/building-rtl-aware-web-apps-and-websites-part-1/)? [Follow Button Docs](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/widgets/generate/follow-button/)

```html
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/follow/1/?uri=spotify:artist:6sFIWsNpZYqfjUpaCgueju&size=detail&theme=light" width="300" height="56" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden;" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit the content within an iframe since it is handled by the external site, if you mean if it can be done structurally.

If you mean will it be displayed right to left for certain languages - the Spotify follow button will be displayed in the correct language based on the browser's configured language preferences. Even with Arabic, Hebrew and other RtL written languages set as browser preference, Spotify doesn't have a special right-to-left display for the button, or change the language of the button at all.

E.g. with English in browser language settings:

[image]

and with French in browser language settings:

[image]